# Can i use Angular material and angular data grid in the same project?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-grid

My project is based on a table so i guess i need to use angular data grid.
i don't want to start from scratch. i want to use angular grid to create my table and angular material for the rest.
[table created with angular material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg1c7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it,

Here i have attached [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dialog-data-grid-gynymo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-content-example-dialog.html) demo, take a look